# In $\mathbb{R}^n$, does continuity on paths imply continuity?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, curves, connectedness

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and connected (equiv. path connected), and let $f : U \to \mathbb{R}$. Is it true that if $f$ is continuous on all paths, that is, if for all continuous $\gamma : [0,1] \to U$, $f \circ \gamma$ is continuous, then $f$ must be continuous?

If this is true, could we weaken the hypotheses on $U$ in any nice way?

Comment: What did you try to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true, and is a special case of the result proved in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2446199/19006

Comment: So it's a dupe?

Comment: Instead of answering like that one should vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Noted, thanks :)