# Are homotopy-preserving maps continuous?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I was thinking some about weak homotopy equivalences and what happens when you drop the continuity assumption.
For example, it's not too hard to come up with non-continuous functions that induce isomorphisms on all homotopy groups (and a bijection on connected components): let $X$ be any contractible space, then the identity map $\operatorname{codisc}X\to X$ from the codiscrete topology on $X$ is not continuous in general, but it trivially induces isomorphisms of all $\pi_n$ as both spaces are contractible.

My question is if continuity remains unnecessary if I strengthen the assumptions a bit from just inducing homomorphisms of homotopy groups to actually just preserving homotopies:

**Question:** Does there exist a non-continuous map $f:X\to Y$ such that $\def\bS{\mathbb{S}}fg:\bS^n\to Y$ is continuous for all continuous $g:\bS^n\to X$ and $n\geq0$, where $\bS^n$ is the $n$-sphere?

I want to believe that the answer is yes, but I am drawing blanks for an explicit example.
I thought to use length constraints on homotopies like what happens with the [long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)) (each individual homotopy is "too small" to see everything), but I couldn't put it into practice.

If the answer to the question is indeed yes, then how nice can $X$ and $Y$ be with $f$ still existing? For instance, can $X$ and $Y$ be [compactly generated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactly_generated_space) and ([weakly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_Hausdorff_space)) Hausdorff?

Comment: In particular, continuity of arbitrary maps out of $X$ is detected by composing with maps from spheres iff $X$ is $\mathbb{R}$-generated in the sense of my answer there.  (This is easy to prove since spheres themselves are $\mathbb{R}$-generated, being locally path-connected and first countable.)

Comment: For a *really* simple example, you can take $X$ to be an arbitrary non-discrete space that is totally path-disconnected, let $Y$ be $X$ with the discrete topology, and $f$ be the identity function.

Comment: @Eric ah, I can't believe I missed the simple example, but thank you for pointing out the near-duplicate. If you want, you can post it as an answer (though I'm not sure what the etiquette is for near-duplicates...)

Comment: I can either write an answer or just mark this question as a duplicate, whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not impose some hypothesis related to path-connectedness on $X$, then there are essentially arbitrarily nice counterexamples.  For example, let $X$ any totally path-disconnected space (e.g., $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ which is additionally compact Hausdorff) and $Y$ be any space.  Then every map $f:X\to Y$ has continuous composition with every map from a sphere, so such a counterexample exists unless *every* map from $X$ to $Y$ is continuous.

Note that spheres are a bit of a red herring here--it's equivalent to ask for the same condition with $\mathbb{R}$ (or $[0,1]$) in place of spheres.  One direction is easy (any interval in $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as a quotient of a sphere so if you have continuity after composing with maps from spheres you get continuity after composing with maps from $\mathbb{R}$).  The other direction is nontrivial (see below).

More generally, say a space $X$ is *$\mathbb{R}$-generated* if for every space $Y$ and every function $f:X\to Y$, $f$ is continuous iff its composition with each continuous map $\mathbb{R}\to X$ is continuous.  I discuss such spaces in detail in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1406308/86856).  In particular, every locally path-connected first-countable space is $\mathbb{R}$-generated, as is every CW-complex, and every $\mathbb{R}$-generated space is locally path-connected.  If $Z$ is $\mathbb{R}$-generated and $f:X\to Y$ has the property that its composition with every continuous map $\mathbb{R}\to X$ is continuous, then $f$ also has the same property with respect to maps $Z\to X$.  In particular, taking $Z$ to be the spheres, this proves the nontrivial direction mentioned in the previous paragraph.  It follows that the $\mathbb{R}$-generated spaces are exactly the spaces $X$ for which no counterexample $f:X\to Y$ exists to your question.