# Topology determined by cubes

Tags: general-topology, geometry, continuity, category-theory, limits-colimits

Which spaces $X$ have the property that $X \to Y$ is continuous if and only if $I^n \to X \to Y$ is continuous for all $I^n \to X$?

*Example:* manifolds and CW complexes have this property, since we have surjective maps $I^n \to \Delta^n$ and $\bigcup_{k \geq 0} I^n \to \bigcup_{k \geq 0} \mathrm{Ball}(0, k) = \mathbb{R}^n$. This concludes since we can always deduce continuity “locally” on CW complexes and manifolds.

I am particularly interested to the case $X=\mathbb{E}_{\infty}(n)$ for all $n$. This would settle a minor doubt I had on $\mathbb{E}_{\infty}$-ring spectra, but I think the context is irrelevant.

Comment: Is $n$ a fixed natural?

Comment: These are the [numerically generated spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Delta-generated+topological+space).

Comment: Near-duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406162/do-there-exist-general-conditions-under-which-we-can-conclude-that-continuity-on (It is easy to see that the condition there is equivalent to yours)

Comment: Nice! It is enough for me to know that $\mathbb{E}_{\infty}(n)$ Is $\Delta$-generated for all $n$. I will add this example to the question. If you mind to answer to the example (follows from cocontinuity and the observation that $Conf_n(\mathbb{R}^k) $ is a manifold), I will accept your answer.